# In Codeception, is it possible to intercept and modify HTTP responses before they are parsed? If so, how?

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, xss, codeception

I am new to [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) and I am researching using it to run our integration / acceptance test suite (currently some phpunit scripts...). It seems like a very interesting tool but I've run into an issue that could prevent us from using it.

I'm trying to find a way to inject a middleware or create a module that will allow me to strip the [JSON protection string](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection) from our server's response before it's decoded by the REST module.

The JSON is prefixed with `")]}',\n"` to make the object invalid, which protects against a type of CSRF vulnerability in some browsers, but it breaks `json_decode()` (intentionally) and the Codeception REST validation methods.

I'm looking for a way to modify the response, to strip off the prefix, before the test suite begins using the data. Does anyone know if that's possible? Or if there are any built-in ways to work with or rewrite response bodies?

Unfortunately, removing the prefix from the server output is not an option. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You can create a helper that will both modify the result and assert it, see this link for more information http://codeception.com/07-12-2012/assertions-in-helpers.html

Comment: That's interesting, but it looks like it would mean that I have to re-implement every json-related assertion in the REST module, which might not be too bad but I'd prefer to avoid it. I was able to extend the browser module which seemed promising but there's a very weird inheritance model happening using reflection and calling even protected methods in the child class results in access exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify HTTP response content before it is parsed by REST module.

REST module uses `PhpBrowser` or some Framefork module as HTTP-client. 
So to remove JSON protection string you need to create your own module that extends `PhpBrowser` and overrides `_getResponseContent()` method and then use this module in REST module config as dependency.

Let's assume I have REST method `http://example.dev/api/v1/test` that returns following JSON string with protection prefix

```
)]}'
{"test":"smest"}
```

**/tests/api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            depends: \Helper\MyPhpBrowser
            url: 'http://example.dev/api/v1/'      
        - \Helper\Api
```

**/tests/_support/Helper/MyPhpBrowser.php**

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

class MyPhpBrowser extends \Codeception\Module\PhpBrowser
{
    public function _getResponseContent()
    {
        $rawContent = (string)$this->client->getInternalResponse()->getContent();

        // Here we're going to delete protection prefix from response content 
        $rawContent = preg_replace("/^\)\]\}'\n/", "", $rawContent);

        return $rawContent;
    }
}
```

**/api/smestCept.php**

```
<?php 
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);

$I->sendGET('test');

$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['test' => 'smest']);
```

**Result**

```
$ codecept run api smestCept.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.4
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Api Tests (1) -------------------------------------
✔ smestCept:  (0.29s)
---------------------------------------------------


Time: 579 ms, Memory: 12.50MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. This is the answer and is actually almost exactly the solution I ended up building (thanks to Dominick's post). I had an unrelated bug in my code that I was overlooking because I thought I was going about it wrong, thank you for confirming I was on the right track!!